# h2o randomforest not predicting on a categorical value which not seen during training, It's giving exception

Tags: random-forest, h2o

We are using Prediction Service Builder by using Java POJO for serving our model. But when we pass a new categorical value of a feature which model haven't seen before while training. It gives an exception. How can i handle that ?

Comment: I think the easiest fix might be to just choose a training set which includes all categories.  You could also scrub the real world data to map outlier never before seen categories to known categories.

Comment: This question is also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093030/training-model-with-multiple-features-whos-values-are-conceptually-the-same/45094060#45094060

Answer (score 2):

The Java POJO and MOJO documentation for H2O-3 is here:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

The relevant example at the POJO level is pasted below:

```
String modelClassName = "gbm_pojo_test";
hex.genmodel.GenModel rawModel;
rawModel = (hex.genmodel.GenModel) Class.forName(modelClassName).newInstance();

// By default, unknown categorical levels throw PredictUnknownCategoricalLevelException.
// Optionally configure the wrapper to treat unknown categorical levels as N/A instead
// and strings that cannot be converted to numbers also to N/As:
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(
         new EasyPredictModelWrapper.Config()
             .setModel(rawModel)
             .setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true)
             .setConvertInvalidNumbersToNa(true)
);
```

Incidentally, if you use MOJOs instead of POJOs, you won't have to compile any DRF Java model code at all, which can be an issue for large models.  Here is an example project which builds a tree model, exports a MOJO, creates a WAR file, and deploys it in a really simple Java servlet container:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-mojo-servlet

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when making predictions in R. I needed to use models that were version agnostic (either POJO or MOJO) and not having a h2o cluster running was a bonus.

I figured that if you save your model as a MOJO (this workaround does not work in POJOs), and not feed the variables that are throwing an error when you call the `h2o.predict_json()` function, the model will work as intended.

My code which makes predictions (regression) based on input from a .csv file can be summed to this:

```
dataset <- read.csv(<filepath>)
dataset$error_column <- ""
dataset$prediction <- 0
dataset_good <- dataset[0,]
dataset_error <- dataset[0,]
variables <- c(<variable1>, <variable2>, <...>, <variableN>)

while (length(dataset[,1]>0){

    # make predictions without feeding variables identified as problematic #
    dataset$prediction <- setNames(unlist(h2o.predict_json(model = <model_path>, 
                          json = toJSON(dataset[, setdiff(variables, unlist(strsplit(dataset$error_column, split="; ")))]))), "prediction")

    # save good predictions in one table #
    dataset_good <- rbind(dataset_good, dataset[!is.na(as.numeric(dataset$prediction)),])

    # save errors in another dataset #
    dataset_error <- rbind(dataset_error, dataset[is.na(as.numeric(dataset$prediction)),])

    # identify problematic variable in message #
    dataset_error$error_column <- paste(dataset_error$error_column,
                                  substr(dataset_error$prediction, start = regexpr("\\(", dataset_error$prediction)+1, 
                                                                   stop = regexpr(",", dataset_error$prediction)-1 ), sep = "; ")

    # rerun rows that generated errors #
    dataset <- dataset_error
}
```

Don't forget you need to have the h2o-genmodel as well as the MOJO.